# How can I sum up values by date(month) in report builder 3.0 graphs?

Tags: reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to sum the data points by Months instead of individual days. The data is originating from an SQL Query so I'm thinking this may be the only way to do that. However, I would much rather do this inside of Report Builder 3.0. Any hints on how to do this?

For example, I want to see the number of tickets for the Months of December and January as only two seperate data points.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you  create a new field ( calculated perhaps) onthe dataset and group by that?

else you should be able to create an expression on the graph's group that groups by Month of a certain field.